# DrawImage() doesn't draw on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage

I am trying to make a screen following the player so that the player is in the middle of the screen. I have already made it in another game, but here it doesn't work. Here is my code :

```js
var c = document.getElementById("main");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var screen = document.getElementById("screen").getContext("2d");
var WhatUSeeWidth = document.getElementById("screen").width;
var WhatUSeeHeight = document.getElementById("screen").height;

ctx.beginPath();
for (i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
    if (i % 2) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    }
    else {
      ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    }
    ctx.fillRect(0, i * 100, 500, 100);
} 

var player = {
 x : 700,
 y : 800
}

setInterval(tick, 100);

function tick() {
  screen.beginPath();
  screen.drawImage(c, player.x - WhatUSeeWidth / 2, player.y - WhatUSeeHeight / 2, WhatUSeeWidth, WhatUSeeHeight, 0, 0, WhatUSeeWidth, WhatUSeeHeight);
}
```

```css
canvas {
     border: 2px solid black;
   }
```

```html
<canvas id="main" width="500" height="500"h></canvas>
 <canvas id="screen" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

I want to draw The Blue and red canvas in The "screen" canvas Using drawImage

Comment: I ran your snippet, it created a patter of red, blue, and white. How *"it doesn't work"*?

Comment: It doesn't draw The red and blue canvas in The other canvas under neath it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , from your comment I understood what you are looking for. But the problem is that you probably start by an example without having understood. I try to give you my interpretation of what you do , but you should look for a good guide that starts with the basics and deepen animations (for example this: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/).

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvasLayer" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasLayer");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var WhatUSeeWidth = document.getElementById("canvasLayer").width;
var WhatUSeeHeight = document.getElementById("canvasLayer").height;

var player = {
    x : 0,
    y : 0
}

function drawBackground() {
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
      if (i % 2) {
        context.fillStyle = "red";
      }
      else {
        context.fillStyle = "blue";
      }
      context.fillRect(0, i * 100, 500, 100);
  } 
}

function playerMove() {
  context.beginPath();
  var radius = 5;
  context.arc(player.x, player.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'green';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  context.stroke();
}

setInterval(tick, 100);

function tick() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBackground();

  player.x++;
  player.y++;
  playerMove();
}
```

[This is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aozgx4rc/2/).

**EDIT WITH THE CORRECT ANSWER**

The error is in the position of the object "player". It is located outside of the canvas, width:500 height:500 and the "player" is in position x:700 y:800.

Changing the position of the player your copy will appear.

```
var player = {
    x : 50,
    y : 50
}
```

[Here the jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/aozgx4rc/3/)

Comment: I want to draw The Blue and red canvas in The screen canvas. But it does not work...

Comment: You havn't understood : When The red and blue drawing is finished, clear The screen canvas, and then copy The canvas on to The screen canvas putting The player in The middle of The screen canvas. I'm mot English, so sorry for my English...

Comment: It is just copying The canvas and inserting it in The other canvas.

Comment: Ok , I hope you understand. In your code the thing wrong is the position of the player ( or coordinates that calculations on the "drawImage" ), watch this: https://jsfiddle.net/aozgx4rc/3/  you just change the coordinates of "player", because 700x800 draws the copy out of the "screen" canvas.

Comment: So what really does answer the question is this comment... You should edit the post.

Comment: You are right... I think the comment is the right answer. Now change the answer.